# Unnest Pandas DF list into separate columns python

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pandas DF with a nested column and would like to split them up into its own columns. (explode doesn't seem to work because of this nested structure)

Input:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     col1|                                                                                                 col2|
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      100|[('abc', 'customer'), ('product_b', 'product'), ('xyz','customer'), ('product_a', 'product')]        |
|      101|[('mno', 'customer')                                                                                 |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Output:

+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|     col1|        customer|                product  |      
+---------+------------------------------------------+
|      100|['abc', 'xyz']  |['product_b', 'product_a']
|      101|['mno']         |                         |
+---------+------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`.pivot()`** and **`groupBy`** spark built in functions.

```
l=[('abc', 'customer'), ('product_b', 'product'), ('xyz', 'customer'), ('product_a', 'product')]

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2']).\
groupBy("col2").\
agg(collect_list(col("col1")).alias("col1")).\
groupBy(lit(1)).\
pivot("col2").agg(first(col("col1"))).\
drop("1").\
show(10,False)
#+----------+----------------------+
#|customer  |product               |
#+----------+----------------------+
#|[abc, xyz]|[product_b, product_a]|
#+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! The list is already a column in the DF and am trying to do this on a per-row basis. For e.g. 

colA list
1      [('abc', 'customer'), ('product_b', 'product'), ('xyz', 'customer'), ('product_a', 'product')]
2      [('abc', 'customer'), ('product_b', 'product')]

Comment: @thecoder, Could you try to create spark df from pandas df then print schema by using: `spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF).printSchema()` and update the question with the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
out = pd.DataFrame(input).groupby(1)[0].agg(list).to_frame().T
Out[170]: 
1    customer                 product
0  [abc, xyz]  [product_b, product_a]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a solution using numpy, pulling the values and columns data appropriately, and then creating a Pandas DataFrame for them**

```py
# Import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load data into numpy array
data = np.array([('abc', 'customer'), ('product_b', 'product'), ('xyz', 'customer'), ('product_a', 'product')]).astype(str)

# Get all values (i.e product/customer name) and categories (product or customer)
values = data[:,0]
types = data[:,1]
categories = np.unique(types)

# Get customer and product names
customers = values[np.where(types == categories[0])[0]]        # This finds all the pairs with type customer
products = values[np.where(types == categories[1])[0]]         # This finds all the pairs with type product

# Put numpy data into DataFrame
d = {'Customer': customers.tolist(), 'Products': products.tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```